# Python - Find, extract archives in sub folders and delete after extraction

Tags: python-3.x, file-io, archive

I have a lot of sub folders containing zip files. I want find all zips, extract where they are and delete after extraction. So far I've managed to write this:

```
import zipfile,fnmatch,os

rootPath = r"."
pattern = '*.zip'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
        print(os.path.join(root, filename))
        zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(root, filename)).extractall(os.path.join(root, os.path.splitext(filename)[0]))
```

I find and extract all the zips but no matter how I try to delete a zip I get an access denied error. Is this a proper way of implementing what I'm after? How can I delete archives after extraction?

Thx